# Grails using auto id to create additional property at domain persistence

Tags: grails, persistence, grails-orm

There's surely a better way?

I want to use the auto generated id to create another custom id. Current I'm using the afterInsert method below...

```
def afterInsert() {
    def Instance = TttTicket.get(this.id)
    Instance.number = project.ticketPrepender + id.toString().padLeft( 5, '0' )
    Instance.save()
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest a better way?

Yes.

The best thing to do depends on some factors like why this property exists, will it ever change and where do you need access to it.

One option is to make the `number` transient, remove the `number` field and have a `getNumber()` method which returns something like `project.ticketPrepender + id.toString().padLeft( 5, '0' )`.

Comment: left padding an `id` with zeroes is a weird thing to do for any context other than presentation.  If that is all you are using this value for, I would leave it out of the domain altogether and let that be a presentation concern, like a GSP tag for GSPs, corresponding `.gson` logic for JSON Views, etc.

Comment: Yes the padded id is purely for presentation purposes. Once created it would never change. I want to keep the auto generated index as I do not like to tamper with default behavior but have a custom ticket id to display to the users. E.g. TTT000100. I could have done this inside my client Angular app but want to cut down on front-end adaptations (Not for performance reasons).  Thank you for your advice :-)

Comment: BTW - BIG fan of Grails! Thank you for taking the time to personally answer this question ;-)

Comment: For anyone who's interested I applied the custom padding to the index id using Jeff's suggestion with in the gson view as follows:-

Comment: import restapi.TttTicket

model {
 TttTicket tttTicket
}

json g.render(tttTicket, [deep:true, resolveTemplate: false]){
 number tttTicket.project.ticketPrepender + tttTicket.id.toString().padLeft( 5, '0' )
}